# Purpose of primary group

Tags: active-directory, groups

Why do we need a ***primary group*** for users? Why is it mandatory to the users to have a ***primary group***?

Answer (score 2):

As per the text next to the "Primary Group" button, this setting applies only for POSIX applications and Mac clients.

[image]

Is it not needed for every day Active Directory usage and can safely be ignored by almost everyone. If you don't know what it's for, you don't need it.

Comment: I tried to remove all the groups from the Member Of table. When I tried removing the last group it showed a pop up that "Primary Group cannot be removed Please select another group as primary group and remove it". Why should a user have a primary group? what happens if a group is selected as a primary group?

Comment: @GaneshR - perhaps you should explain exactly why you want to remove a user from all their groups? The user *must* be a member of at least one group. If you need to, change their primary group to something else and then remove the group. A user that is a member of no groups is useless.

Comment: I am new to AD. I am in the learning stage. I am wondering why should a user be a member of atleast one group and why should it be a primary group? Creating a user assigns Domain Users as its primary group. Why is that so?

Comment: @GaneshR - I can see why this question was originally put on hold. This is not the place to get answers to questions like that; we're here to answer questions about specific solvable problems. If you're just starting out, you might want to do some background reading first.

Comment: On Un*x / Linux it's for setting the group that will be set on files that are created by that user: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503162/what-is-the-signifance-of-the-primary-group-of-a-user/503163#503163

Comment: `If you don't know what it's for, you don't need it.` That's one way to avoid answering a question.